# Getting PHP Syntax error “unexpected T_FOREACH” on Line 151

Tags: php

I am getting an error on line 151 on my foreach construct and I don't know why?
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in engine\inc\video_part.php on line 151

```
    $save_con                  = $_POST['save_con'];
    $save_con['on_off']        = intval($save_con['on_off']);
    $save_con['full_or_field'] = intval($save_con['full_or_field']);
    $save_con['nav_mod']       = intval($save_con['nav_mod']);
    $save_con['next_prev']     = intval($save_con['next_prev']);
    $save_con['ajax_nav']      = intval($save_con['ajax_nav']);
    $save_con['prefix']        = $save_con['prefix'];
    $save_con['fields']        = $save_con['fields']; 



  $find    = array();
    $replace = array();

    $find[]    = "'\r'";
    $replace[] = "";
    $find[]    = "'\n'";
    $replace[] = "";

    $handler = fopen(ENGINE_DIR . '/data/video_part_config.php', "w");

    fwrite($handler, "<?PHP \n\n//Video Part System by MaRZoCHi & Gameer\n\n\$video_part_config = array (\n\n'version' => \"2.5\",\n\n");
    foreach ($save_con as $name => $value) {             <- line 151 error


        fwrite($handler, "'{$name}' => \"{$value}\",\n\n");
    }
    fwrite($handler, ");\n\n?>");
    fclose($handler);

    clear_cache();
    msg("info", $lang['opt_sysok'], "<font color=\"green\"><b>{$lang['opt_sysok_1']}</b></font>", "$PHP_SELF?mod=video_part");
}

?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the right code? I'd have guessed at a missing semi-colon on line 150, but that's present and my IDE isn't flagging a syntax error at all.

Comment: Line 150 `\"2.5\"` it should be `\'2.5\'`

Comment: Of course this plugin should work on video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9kufFxP9uQ

Answer (score 0):

check brackets in this line,

```
fwrite($handler, "<?PHP \n\n//Video Part System by MaRZoCHi & Gameer\n\n\$video_part_config = array (\n\n'version' => \"2.5\",\n\n");
```

to

```
fwrite($handler, "<?PHP \n\n//Video Part System by MaRZoCHi & Gameer\n\n\$video_part_config = array (\n\n'version' => \"2.5\",\n\n"));
```

Comment: it should be a comment @Ayyanar G

Comment: you have 2 open brackets (fwrite and array )in this line but closed only once.

Comment: I replaced the line of code still getting the same error.

Comment: Figured out what was wrong author of the code in the first line missed <?PHP in video_part.php now everything works fine.